# MVVM : Binding Command with Observable collection to Listbox and taking values from textbox

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am new in MVVM, in this small app i have a listbox ,three textboxes and two buttons one is Update and another is Add. In the XAML i have done binding of all listbox columns with textboxes, according to command my update button functions properly when i change values in either of textboxes but i am not aware how to take values from textboxes and add values in collection by using command .

Here is the Xaml code.

```
<Grid Height="314">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <ListView Name="ListViewEmployeeDetails" Grid.Row="1" Margin="4,109,12,23"  ItemsSource="{Binding Products}"  >
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView x:Name="grdTest">
                <GridViewColumn Header="ID" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding ID}"  Width="100"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}"  Width="100" />
                <GridViewColumn Header="Price" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Price}" Width="100" />
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
    <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="80,7,0,0" Name="txtID" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="178" Text="{Binding ElementName=ListViewEmployeeDetails,Path=SelectedItem.ID}" />
    <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="80,35,0,0" Name="txtName" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="178" Text="{Binding ElementName=ListViewEmployeeDetails,Path=SelectedItem.Name}" />
    <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="80,61,0,0" Name="txtPrice" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="178" Text="{Binding ElementName=ListViewEmployeeDetails,Path=SelectedItem.Price}" />
    <Label Content="ID" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,12,0,274" Name="label1" />
    <Label Content="Price" Grid.Row="1" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,59,0,0" Name="label2" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
    <Label Content="Name" Grid.Row="1" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,35,0,0" Name="label3" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
    <Button Content="Update" Grid.Row="1" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="311,59,0,0" Name="btnUpdate"
            VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="141"
            Command="{Binding Path=UpdateCommad}"
            />
    <Button Content="Add" Grid.Row="1" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="311,17,0,0" Name="btnAdd"
        VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="141"
        Command="{Binding UpdateCommad}"
            />
</Grid>
```

And here is the Product class

```
public class Product : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private int m_ID;
    private string m_Name;
    private double m_Price;
    #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
    #endregion

    public int ID
    {
        get
        {
            return m_ID;
        }
        set
        {
            m_ID = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("ID");
        }
    }
    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return m_Name;
        }
        set
        {
            m_Name = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Name");
        }
    }
    public double Price
    {
        get
        {
            return m_Price;
        }
        set
        {
            m_Price = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Price");
        }
    }
}
```

here is the ViewModel Class, now i am statically adding product into m_Products.

```
class ProductViewModel
{
    private ObservableCollection<Product> m_Products;
    public ProductViewModel()
    {
        m_Products = new ObservableCollection<Product>
    {
        new Product {ID=1, Name ="Pro1", Price=10},
        new Product{ID=2, Name="BAse2", Price=12}
    };
    }
    public ObservableCollection<Product> Products
    {
        get
        {
            return m_Products;
        }
        set
        {
            m_Products = value;
        }
    }
    private ICommand mUpdater;
    public ICommand UpdateCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (mUpdater == null)
                mUpdater = new Updater();
            return mUpdater;
        }
        set
        {
            mUpdater = value;
        }
    }
    private ICommand addUpdater;
    public ICommand AddCommand
    {
        get 
        {
            if (addUpdater == null)
                addUpdater = new Updater();
            return addUpdater; 
        }
        set
        {
            addUpdater = value;
        }
    }



    private class Updater : ICommand
    {
        #region ICommand Members
        public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            return true;
        }
        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;
        public void Execute(object parameter)
        {
        }
        #endregion
    }
```

}

Now i dont know how to add values(Product) into collection by using command on Add button click.

Comment: In ListBox whrn i add new entry then it will update all available entries with new one. I am using Observable Collection, so is this a problem?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [relay command](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx#id0090030). It allows you to inject the command's logic via delegates passed into its constructor:

```
/// <summary>
/// Class representing a command sent by a button in the UI, defines what to launch when the command is called
/// </summary>
public class RelayCommand : ICommand
{
    #region Fields

    readonly Action<object> _execute;
    readonly Predicate<object> _canExecute;

    #endregion // Fields

    #region Constructors

    public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute)
        : this(execute, null)
    {
    }

    public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute, Predicate<object> canExecute)
    {
        if (execute == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("execute");

        _execute = execute;
        _canExecute = canExecute;
    }
    #endregion // Constructors

    #region ICommand Members

    //[DebuggerStepThrough]
    /// <summary>
    /// Defines if the current command can be executed or not
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="parameter"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return _canExecute == null || _canExecute(parameter);
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
        remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        _execute(parameter);
    }

    #endregion // ICommand Members
}
```

With this type of command its very easy do what you want, for example in your viewmodel you can do this now:

```
public class ProductViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private ObservableCollection<Product> m_Products;
    public ProductViewModel()
    {
        m_Products = new ObservableCollection<Product>
        {
            new Product {ID = 1, Name = "Pro1", Price = 10},
            new Product {ID = 2, Name = "BAse2", Price = 12}
        };
    }


    private Product _selectedProduct;
    public Product SelectedProduct
    {
        get
        {
            return _selectedProduct;
        }
        set
        {
            _selectedProduct = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("SelectedProduct");
        }
    }
    public ObservableCollection<Product> Products
    {
        get
        {
            return m_Products;
        }
        set
        {
            m_Products = value;
        }
    }

    ICommand _addCommand;
    public ICommand AddCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (_addCommand == null)
            {
                _addCommand = new RelayCommand(param => AddItem());
            }
            return _addCommand;
        }
    }


    ICommand _deleteCommand;
    public ICommand DeleteCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (_deleteCommand == null)
            {
                _deleteCommand = new RelayCommand(param => DeleteItem((Product)param));
            }
            return _deleteCommand;
        }
    }

    private void DeleteItem(Product product)
    {
        if (m_Products.Contains(product))
        {
            m_Products.Remove(product);
        }
    }

    private void AddItem()
    {
        m_Products.Add(new Product());

    }


    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

As you can see, there are two commands, one to add a Product and other to delete the selected product.You don't have to worry about the update, you are using an ObservableCollection<>.Also, I add the property selectedProduct to your ViewModel to know what element was selected in your view:

```
    <Grid Height="314">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <ListView Name="ListViewEmployeeDetails" Grid.Row="1" Margin="4,109,12,23"  ItemsSource="{Binding Products}" SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedProduct}"  >
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView x:Name="grdTest">
                <GridViewColumn Header="ID" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding ID}"  Width="100" />
                <GridViewColumn Header="Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}"  Width="100" />
                <GridViewColumn Header="Price" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Price}" Width="100" />
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
    <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="80,7,0,0" Name="txtID" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="178" Text="{Binding SelectedProduct.ID}" />
    <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="80,35,0,0" Name="txtName" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="178" Text="{Binding SelectedProduct.Name}" />
    <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="80,61,0,0" Name="txtPrice" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="178" Text="{Binding SelectedProduct.Price}" />
    <Label Content="ID" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,12,0,274" Name="label1" />
    <Label Content="Price" Grid.Row="1" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,59,0,0" Name="label2" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
    <Label Content="Name" Grid.Row="1" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,35,0,0" Name="label3" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
    <Button Content="Remove" Grid.Row="1" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="311,59,0,0" Name="btnUpdate"
        VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="141"
        Command="{Binding DeleteCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedProduct}"
        />
    <Button Content="Add" Grid.Row="1" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="311,17,0,0" Name="btnAdd"
    VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="141"
    Command="{Binding AddCommand}"
        />
</Grid>
```

In the delete button I declare the CommandParamameter and I bound it  to the  SelectedProduct property. This is the param that receive the RelayCommand to delete a product. It is no necessary, you have already in the viewmodel the SelectedProduct, but I did it anyway to show how you can pass a parameter to a command.

**[EDIT 1]**

To achieve the behavior that you want you need to add three new properties in your viewModel (Id, Name, and Price).Now those properties should be bounded with TextBoxes. To edit a selected product in your ListView, in the set of the SelectedProduct property you need to set too the values of the ID, Name and Prices properties. You have to set the properties of the selected product when a textbox change its value too.

Changes in the ViewModel:

```
  private int _id=1;
    public int Id
    {
        get
        {
            return _id;
        }
        set
        {
            _id = value;
            if (SelectedProduct!=null)
            {
                SelectedProduct.ID = _id;
            }
            OnPropertyChanged("Id");
        }
    }

    private string _name;
    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return _name;
        }
        set
        {
            _name = value;
            if (SelectedProduct != null)
            {
                SelectedProduct.Name = _name;
            }
            OnPropertyChanged("Name");
        }
    }


    private double _price = 0;
    public double Price
    {
        get
        {
            return _price;
        }
        set
        {
            _price = value;
            if (SelectedProduct != null)
            {
                SelectedProduct.Price = _price;
            }
            OnPropertyChanged("Price");
        }
    }

    private Product _selectedProduct;
    public Product SelectedProduct
    {
        get
        {
            return _selectedProduct;
        }
        set
        {
            _selectedProduct = value;

            Id = _selectedProduct != null ? _selectedProduct.ID : 0;
            Name = _selectedProduct != null ? _selectedProduct.Name : "";
            Price = _selectedProduct != null ? _selectedProduct.Price : 0;

            OnPropertyChanged("SelectedProduct");
        }
    }
```

Changes in your View:

```
<TextBox Grid.Row="1" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="80,7,0,0" Name="txtID" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="178" Text="{Binding Id}" />
<TextBox Grid.Row="1" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="80,35,0,0" Name="txtName" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="178" Text="{Binding Name}" />
<TextBox Grid.Row="1" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="80,61,0,0" Name="txtPrice" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="178" Text="{Binding Price}" />
```

Comment: Can i use this RelayCommand for add, update and delete, if so then how can i do update and delete ?

Comment: What is your logic int the update. When you select one product in the listview, you want to see its fields in the textboxes to edit them?

Comment: yes exactly... and i want a delete button too for deleting current item.

Comment: Hi @PraveenDeewan, I edit my answer. Now you can do the three functions that you want (Add,Update,Delete)

Comment: text boxes are not bounded with AddItem that's why when I add new item then 0 , blank,0 is added in listbox and also delete not working

Comment: The behavior of the addItem is add a new product with predeterminated values, not using the values of the texboxes. If you want to change the values of an added item you have to select it in the listview and changes its values. I don’t understand why the delete not work for you, check if you are writing well the name of the SelectedProduct property. I edit my answer to achieve the behavior that you want in the add product(EDIT 1).

Comment: Hi @octavioccl, i have used this new code in viewmodel :                 private static Product productInfo = new Product();
        public Product ProductInfo
        {
            get { return productInfo; }
        }    by this code i can bind all textboxes to all three prop of Product class and it's working fine, and delete also working it was typo. Thanks for your Assistance.

Comment: Hi @octavioccl, add and delete button work properly but when i update values from textboxes it will update all objects of observable collection what should be the problem ??